# Classification with Accord.net library throw IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, classification, accord.net

I am new to machine learning.
I am using Accord.NET

I have a simple problem of classification, I have some period of time, and each period has it is own type according to the start time of the period and the end time of the period (this is a simplified description of the description)

I tried to write this code to learn the machine but it is always throw

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
List<List<int>> trainingList = ConvertDuruslarToIntegerList();
int[][] inputs = GetInputs(trainingList);
int[] outputs = GetOutpus(trainingList);

int[] distinct = outputs.Distinct().ToArray();
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < distinct.Length; i++)
    dic.Add(distinct[i], i + 1);

List<int> preparedOutput = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < outputs.Length; i++)
    preparedOutput.Add(dic[outputs[i]]);

int classesCount = preparedOutput.Distinct().Count();

var allthings = inputs.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Concat(y).ToArray()).Concat(preparedOutput);
var minAllthings = allthings.Min();
var maxAllthings = allthings.Max();
var symbolsCount = maxAllthings - minAllthings + 1;

var function = new MarkovDiscreteFunction(states: classesCount, symbols: symbolsCount, outputClasses: classesCount);
var classifier = new HiddenConditionalRandomField<int>(function);

// Create a learning algorithm
var teacher = new HiddenResilientGradientLearning<int>(classifier)
{
    MaxIterations = 10
};

// Run the algorithm and learn the models
teacher.Learn(inputs, preparedOutput.ToArray());
```

the exception is thrown in the `teacher.Learn` method

Answer (score 0):

Accord expects classes to be zero-based. You can successfully learn if you change the following line:

```
dic.Add(distinct[i], i);
```